# clearInterval not working when clicked

Tags: javascript, click, setinterval, suspend, clearinterval

Clearinterval is not clearing the interval set. The program is stuck looping waiting for a click. How do I make it clear interval once it detects a click?

```
    var timerID;
    function waitForClick() {
       timerID = setInterval(listen(), 1000);
    }

    function listen() {
       document.getElementById("graphic").onclick = function stopListen() {
          alert("clicky");
          clearInterval(timerID);
       }
    };

    waitForClick();
    return;
```

Comment: Why do you have a `return;` hanging out there by itself?

Comment: This is a subfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is clearing the interval. I believe the issue is your logic and what you're expecting to happen. Let's break down your code a bit:

```
var timerID;
function waitForClick() {
   timerID = setInterval(listen(), 1000);
}
```

Here you've created an interval. However, your interval is actually the return value of `listen`, so you're essentially doing this:

```
timerID = setInterval(undefined, 1000);
```

When setInterval is called, it invokes `listen` (because of `()`), which binds your `onclick` handler to the `graphic` element. This only gets bound once, otherwise you would see multiple `alert` messages. When a user then clicks the `graphic` element, you're alerting "clicky", and then clearing your interval.

The issue, it seems, is that you are then clicking the element again and seeing the alert, and assuming the interval is still running. It's not - you just have an event handler that is still bound!

If you do this:

```
document.getElementById("graphic").onclick = function stopListen() {
    alert('clicky');
    clearInterval(timerID);

    // Clear out event handler
    document.getElementById('graphic').onclick = null;
}
```

You'll see that the alerts stop (because we've explicity set the onclick to null).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2muguog/

I believe what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
function waitForClick() {
    if (!timerId) {
        timerId = setInterval(toInterval, 1000);
        document.getElementById('graphic').onclick = function() {
            alert('clicky');
            clearInterval(timerId);
            timerId = null;
        } 
    }
}

function toInterval() {
    // Logic here - BUT NOT THE CLICK HANDLER
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = Date.now();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2muguog/1/

Clicking should alert and then stop the interval.